# Issues with IE10 and flexbox -- March 2012 draft not working?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-10

I'm trying to get my flexbox layout to be compatible with IE10, which to my knowledge uses the [March 2012 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120322/) of flexboxes. I've tried every freaking syntax and every variation thereof, but to no avail. The IE10 I have installed in Parallels (I'm on a Mac) is version **10.0.9200.16660**, which should make it use the IE10 flexbox style yea?

Here's my code:

```
.uberflex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;

    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;

    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

I've tried what seems like every varition of these terms with "-ms-" prefix and without the "-ms-" prefix (what they use in IE11) but to no avail. The only property of the class my IE console is telling me exists is the **"display: -ms-flexbox"** bit. Am I being very, very slow or have I been using the wrong draft for IE10?? Was there an update to IE10 which makes flexboxes not work or something?

Any information would be immensely helpful, as I've been able to find very little on the subject. Thank you! :-)

Comment: Does http://flexiejs.com/playground/ work in your IE10?

Comment: Yes that appears to be working fine in IE10! I'll have to play around with this, thank you!

Comment: Ignore that site, it seems to use JavaScript to emulate what flexbox *would* look like if your browser doesn't actually support it. Try this and its demo: http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/. As an aside, make sure IE is actually in IE10 mode. Check Developer Tools (F12) or add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` inside `head`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a guess, but try switching the order to

```
.uberflex {

    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;

    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```